# Share data across Amazon Elastic Beanstalk nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spring-boot, share, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a spring boot application which downloads around 300 MB of data at start up and saves it to a path `/app/local/mydata`. Currently, I have just one dev environment with a single node and it is not a problem. However, once I create a prod instance with (say) 10 nodes, it would be a waste of data bandwidth for each node to individually download the same 300 MB data. It will put a lot of stress on the service it is downloading the data from. And there is cost associated with data flowing in/out of EC2.

I can build a logic using a touchfile to make sure that only one box downloads the data and others just wait until the download is complete. However, I don't know **where** to download these data such that the other nodes can read it too.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download it to S3 if you want to keep it in a file, but it sounds like you might need to put the data in a database (RDS) or maybe cache it in Redis (ElastiCache).

I'm not sure what a "touchfile" is but I assume you  mean some sort of file lock mechanism. I don't see that as the best option for coordinating this across multiple servers. I would probably use a DynamoDB table with consistent reads and conditional writes as a distributed locking mechanism.

How often does the data you are downloading change? Perhaps you could just schedule a Lambda function to refresh the data periodically and update a database or something?

In general, you need to stop thinking about using the web server's local file system for this sort of thing.

Comment: The service downloads around 300 MB every 3 hours. There is already a `@Scheduled` Spring annotation to trigger the download every 3 hours.

The 'touchfile' trick is indeed what you understod. And I agree it is not a good way to go about it. I like your suggestion of using S3. Can it be written to and read from as you could from a Java `FileSystem`? If not, then I would have a problem because the library I am using downloads data to a `FileSystem`. I can't modify the library, unfortunately.

Comment: That seems like something that would be best handled as a scheduled job that runs on a single server. You might be able to schedule this via Lambda if it takes less than 5 minutes to download and process the data. Otherwise a cron job would probably work best.

Comment: I would suggest learning more about the different AWS services available to you and how they work. Using `@Scheduled` means that the job is going to run on every web server. So now you've got to deal with concurrency issues and also worry about Elastic Beanstalk scale-down operations killing the server that might be in the middle of downloading your data. If it was me, I wouldn't be running scheduled jobs on Elastic Beanstalk at all.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Your comments did help. I'll read up on S3 and other services.